# Zooming out with Selenium in Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to zoom out in selenium with Ruby? I have searched the internet and most online answers are in Java, which seems to have some capabilities ruby doesnt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible for you to try the send_keys method. 
In your case, it would be something like this:

```
wait.until do
  waiting = driver.find_element id: "logo"
  waiting.send_keys :control, :subtract
end
```

---

In this example, you can send the keys when the element with the id of logo is found by Selenium when the page is fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can sendkeys, It is available in all programming language.

To zoom in and Zoom out, Here is windows shortcut that you will send using sendkey

CTRL + ALT + L to bring up the lens display view.

CTRL + ALT + D to dock the magnification area.

CTRL + ALT + F brings you back to the full screen mode.

Actions action = new Actions();
  action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).keyDown(keys.ALT).sendKeys("L").perform();

key up and down document
http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/package-summary.html

Here other option is *ASCII VALUE LINK:*
http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `wait.until` syntax has been deprecated.  I was able to get the following to work for my particular project:

```
el = find(button_id)
while not_found
  begin
    find(button_id).click
    not_found = false
  rescue
    el.send_keys [:command, :subtract]
  end
end
```